# Developing using Netlify Dev with Vue JS and Netlify Functions

Tags: vue.js, netlify

I am using vue + netlify for a small web app that uses netlify functions I built.  Everything works fine in production (when I commit to master and netlify auto-deploys based on my master branch) but when I try to use `netlify dev` to spin up a local development instance, calls to the netlify function are failing:

```
VM23:1 POST http://localhost:18002/.netlify/functions/customfunction 404 (Not Found)
```

Clearly the endpoint in the dev enironment is *not* the same, but how do I know what that endpoint may be?  In the console when running the `netlify dev` command it says that the lambda server is listening on 3467... but trying to use endpoint `http://localhost:34567/.netlify/functions/customfunction` results in a CORS error.  Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be getting the CORS error because your server is not running on the same host with your vue app and to fix this you have to set a proxy and for that you need to create a `vue.config.js` file on the project directory (not the vue folder) then past the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:34567' // the port your server in running on
  }
}
```

now your proxy is set so your request URL will the following :

`/.netlify/functions/customfunction`

Doc reference : https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy